# Why ist the MINLP Gap in Gekko Optimisation calculated that way?

Tags: optimization, gekko

I can not comprehend, why they MINLP Gap in Gekko Optimisation Suite is Calculated like you see in the picture. The obj_r ist the optimal Solution of the LP-relaxed Mixed-Integer-Problem, so its the best solution the MIP could possibly get. For my Understanding the difference between obj_i and obj_r should only be decided by obj_r and not the mean Value of obj_r and obj_i. Could anyone explain that to me?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `obj_r` not the best objective of all outstanding relaxations? Anyway, there are different ways one could define the relative gap. This is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The gap between the `obj_r` and `obj-i` is a convergence criterion that is commonly used to terminate MINLP problems early as it represents how much better the solution can potentially become.

- `obj_r` is the lowest objective of all non-integer solutions. It represents the lowest possible potential solution because integer solutions will always be greater than or equal to this objective.
- `obj_i` is the lowest objective of all integer solutions. It is the best possible integer solution up to that point.

The denominator is a normalization that makes the gap a fractional amount instead of an unscaled value. The gap tolerance represents a fractional approach to the optimal solution with a minimum value of 1 to avoid potential divide-by-zero or other issues with very small objective values. The normalization is the average of the best integer and non-integer solutions. If the gap between the best integer solution and lowest non-integer solution is below a particular tolerance `minlp_gap_tol`, the solver terminates with a successful solution message and returns the best integer solution.

The MINLP Gap tolerance is an [APOPT solver option](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) that can be set through Gekko:

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2']
```

This terminates the solution when the gap with 0.01 (1%) of the optimal solution. For example, if the minimization has an optimal objective of 1000, then the solution can potentially terminate when the integer solution gets with 10 of the optimal (1%).

Comment: Not so sure about this being a commonly used tolerance. I don't think I have seen this before. (Which does not say too much).  However, it can understate the true gap by a large amount.

Comment: Good suggestion. The APOPT solver should have an option to define the gap tolerance with fractional (current) or absolute terms.